# How can I insert a new line after 10 characters in C?

Tags: c

I'm reading data from standard input one character at a time and outputting the results to standard output. Every 10 characters, I want to have a new line. For example:

Input-

```
123456789101112
```

Output-

```
1234567891
01112
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
if(numChars = 10) {
    printf("\n");
    numChars = 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever increment `numChars`?

Comment: you might try equality `==` rather than assignment `=`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char test[] = "123456789101112123133431234567891011121231334312345678910111212313343";

    int i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(test))
    {
        printf("%c", test[i++]);
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that use `strlen()` in the condition part of a loop is not a particularly good idea — unless the string being measured changes length.  Call it once before the loop and use the value returned.

Comment: You might consider `if (i % 10 != 0) putchar('\n');` after the loop to finish the last line of output.